# Concatenating two arrays

Tags: c, arrays, string, concatenation

I was trying to create a program that takes in two arrays and concatenates them to create a new string. These are the two strings.

```
 char a[8]={"hellostr"};
 char b[8]={"HELLOSTR"};
```

Can someone tell me how could I concatenate and display this concatenated string? I tried looking for it but could not understand much of it.

Comment: what is (are) `string arrays`?

Comment: I meant two arrays that are declared as strings

Comment: These are not strings. Note that in C, a sting is just a `char []` with a trailing `'\0'`. As you do not reserve enough space for that, it is no string. And: you cannot _declare_ a string - for much the same reason!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make use of [`strcat()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strcat) function from `string.h`.

A sample algo:

1. Define an array (say `destarr[128]`, for example)*large enough* to hold the result (concatenated string).
2. `memset()`the `destarr` to `0`.
3. use `strcat(destarr, a)` and `strcat(destarr, b)` to concatenate one after another.

That said,

```
 char a[ ]={"hellostr"};
```

is considered better and less error-prone over

```
char a[8]={"hellostr"};
```

as,

- In the former case, compiler takes the charge to allocate the memory, as required, with the null-terminator in *mind*. The array can be used as a *string*.
- In the later case, there is no room for the null-terminator and hence, the array can neither be considered nor be used as a *string*.

Comment: Thank you for that example. I had one more question. Now if I want to display just one of the characters from this concatenated string how do I do that?

Comment: I don't agree that the former is less error prone. Because if you intended to have a string exactly x characters long, you don't want code with more characters than that to compile. For example the bugged code `char a[8]={"hellostr"};` should yield a compiler diagnostic, so that hopefully the programmer gets a slap: "hey, you didn't consider null terminarion! Go fix your code to a[8+1]." rather than "everything looks ok here, proceed even though there's potentially a bug here".

Comment: @AnamikaAna `one of the characters` is that what you meant exactly? use index, naturally.

Comment: @SouravGhosh Actually gcc throws no warning for this with max warnings enabled. Very strange.

Comment: @Lundin it should show something along the line of _"excess initializer for array....."_, right?

Comment: @SouravGhosh Indeed. Peculiar since it does so if you write the string as `{'h','e','l','l','o','s','t','r','\0'}`.

Comment: @SouravGhosh I've posted a question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31296727/inconsistent-gcc-diagonistic-for-string-initialization), maybe someone out there knows more :)

Answer (score 0):

`strcat` function can be used.

Header -`string.h`

If you want to do that without `strcat` function then you can write a simple function -

```
  void concatenate(char a[], char b[])
  {
     int c, d;

      c = 0;

     while (a[c] != '\0')
   {
        c++;    
   }

     d = 0;

   while (b[d] != '\0') 
    {
       a[c] = b[d];
       d++;
       c++; 
    }

       a[c] = '\0';
  }
```