# Inconsistent gcc diagnostic for string initialization

Tags: c, gcc, initializer-list

I'm using gcc 4.9.1/Mingw and compiling the code with:

> gcc test.c -otest.exe -std=c11 -pedantic-errors -Wall -Wextra

This code gives a diagnostic:

```
int main (void)
{
  char a[5] = {'h','e','l','l','o','\0'};
}
```

> error: excess elements in array initializer char a[5]

However, this code does not yield a warning:

```
int main (void)
{
  char b[5] = "hello";
}
```

I thought the two forms were 100% equivalent. Is there any reason or subtlety in the C standard etc why the latter should not give a warning?

Or is this a compiler bug? I know that the C standard allows excess initializers, unlike C++, so formally I don't believe gcc is *required* to give a diagnostic. But I would expect the compiler to give warnings consistently.

Comment: Related to: [No compiler error when fixed size char array is initialized without enough room for null terminator](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20694796/1708801)

Comment: The question is similar to the supposed duplicate, but I'm curious about the specific case of inconsistent warnings, which none of the answers to the supposed duplicate is addressing. I believe I also received some better answers here. Re-opening. (Feel free to close the other one as a duplicate to this one, I won't meddle with it since I'm partial :) )

Comment: "*I know that the C standard allows excess initializers, unlike C++*" -- What do you mean by this? As the answer to the duplicate question says, C explicitly permits a string literal of the exact length of the object; C++ does not. C does not permit excess initializers in general; `int arr[2] = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };` is illegal in both languages.

Comment: The warnings are not inconsistent. C has a specific special-case rule for string literals; it has no such rule for braced initializers. In `char b[5] = "hello";` the initializer does not provide a value for `b[5]`.

Comment: @KeithThompson I believe that is indeed why gcc behaves differently for the two cases. Ouah has cited the relevant parts covering both cases.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

While:

```
 char a[5] = {'h','e','l','l','o','\0'};
```

is invalid.

> (C11, 6.7.9p2) "No initializer shall attempt to provide a value for an object not contained within the entity being initialized."

This:

```
char b[5] = "hello";
```

is explicitly allowed by C (emphasis mine):

> (C11, 6.7.9p14) "An array of character type may be initialized by a character string literal or UTF−8 string literal, optionally enclosed in braces. Successive bytes of the string literal (**including the terminating null character if there is room** or if the array is of unknown size) initialize the elements of the array."

But

```
 char b[5] = "hello!";
```

is invalid.

Comment: It would seem to me then that §1 and §14 contradict each other, because a string literal is still an initializer. A bug in the C standard?

Comment: @Lundin I don't take it as a bug but as a special provision when the initializer is a string literal.

Answer (score 10):

It's a weird quirk in the C Standard.  Back in the day, people occasionally used fixed-length, non-null-terminated strings.  (One example was the 14-character filenames in V7 Unix.)  So to let those old programs to continue to compile, it's legal to initialize an explicitly-sized `char` array with a string constant that ends up scraping off the `'\0'`, as you've just observed.

I agree it's surprising that the `{'h','e','l','l','o','\0'}` initializer warned while the `"hello"` one did not.  But these are two very different forms, and it turns out that the rules for them are different.  When you give your array a size and you use the `{}` form, there must be room for all your initializers, period.  But when you give a size and use the `""` form, there's a special exception for that case and that case only.

(It's also not legal in C++ for either form.)

Comment: Albeit the code is valid, issuing a warning for `char b[5] = "hello";` would help most programmers avoid silly bugs. To avoid the warning, an explicit `char b[5] = { 'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o' };` can always be used.

Answer (score 3):

In

```
char b[5] = "hello";
```

`\0` is not appended to the string because array `b` is of size `5`. This is valid. Compiler think of it as

```
char b[5] = {'h','e','l','l','o'};
```

Here `b` is an array of `char`s. But, it can't be used in a place where a string literal is to be supposed. For example, You can't use `b` in `printf` with `%s` specifier or `str` family function.

Comment: Indeed. But why doesn't it warn consistently between the two cases?

Comment: @Lundin; Because compiler knows that if the initializer is string literal then `\0` may or may not be appended depends on the size of array/buffer.

Comment: *not appended to the string because array a* You meant array `b`, right? But this is not enough to explain why `char b[5] = "hello";` is valid while `char b[5] = "hello!";` is not.